# 500 internal server error when Nexmo or Mail fails in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3

For some reason when I make a post request via ajax to a route to send an sms or a mail using Nexmo or Mail, I get a "500 internal server error" and the page blocks and I have to close the window tab and open another.

This happens when something goes wrong, for example: a wrong formatted phone number. In this case, Nexmo writes the error in storage/logs/laravel.log but nothing is returned in controller to output to user, just this "500 error" and the page blocks.

Same thing with the Laravel Mail function.

I'm using Laravel 5.3

Does anyone knows why this is happening ?

Comment: This really doesn't tell us much. What do the logs say? Is there an apache/ngnix log? Something?

Comment: The log tell what the error was, for example "wrong phone number format"..this is what Nexmo writes there. This error should have been returned in controller so I can grab it, but for some reason it;s returned just in logs. No other errors are returned, like missing token or something to suggest this 500 error. I think a package I've installed has "muted" errors returned in controller, and only logges them in file.

Comment: Since you don't know what's causing this, the only thing I can suggest is walking along your code using xDebug or something of that nature, and track where exactly the error is suppressed and the new 500 http code is returned.